# Getting syntax error in Meteor project with node v11.10.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am getting the following error in my meteor project. I am using node v11.10.0 in macOs. Thanks in advance.

> `SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.`
>
> myprojectpath/node_modules/jsforce/node_modules/faye/node_modules/tough-cookie/node_modules/ip-regex/index.js:3
>   const v4 =
>   '(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(?:\.(?:25[0-
>
> ^^^^^ SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.

Comment: Which version of meteor do you use?

Comment: @Vivek --- Meteor 1.3

Comment: That's an old version of meteor. Can you try running ```meteor node -v``` to find the version of node used by meteor.

Comment: Its v0.10.43, how update meteor node ?

Comment: You cannot just update "meteor node", you will need to update the entire meteor application. Please see the migration guide for the appropriate version of meteor that you are using from the official meteor guide.

Answer (score 0):

You could update your meteor (including node) using `meteor update` outside the project and then `meteor update --release && meteor update --all-packages` inside the project and finally enter a `meteor npm meteor reset` and run the project.

To make sure you run the latest npm packages, you may need to check the npm versions. Very helpful is the tool `npm-check-updates` which you can install outside of the project directory:

```
meteor npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

then cd into your project directory and enter

```
meteor npm-check-updates
```

to list your current and the latest available stable versions.

If you rely on the Meteor 1.3 (which I discourage as there are many open security issues in the older Meteor and also in the older Node releases), then you may need to install an older version of `jsforce` in order to get it run again with the older environment you have.

To make sure you have installed the correct npm packages for your 1.3 you can easily check this against a new created project's `package.json` using:

```bash
meteor create --release X.Y.Z some-app-name # replace X.Y.Z with your Meteor version
meteor npm install
cat package.json
```